# Typescript errors with build command in Vite

Tags: reactjs, typescript, vite

I am getting Typescript errors that I want to ignore when I run npm run build with my React + Typescript + Vite project. I am getting errors "className" does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes ..." for example, when using HeadlessUI Tabs.

How can I skip type checking on build?

My tsconfig.json file:

```
{
 "compilerOptions": {
"typeRoots": [ "./node_modules/@types" ],
"target": "ESNext",
"lib": ["DOM", "DOM.Iterable", "ESNext"],
"module": "ESNext",
"skipLibCheck": true,
// "types": ["@types/supabase"],
/* Bundler mode */
"moduleResolution": "node",
"allowImportingTsExtensions": true,
"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
"resolveJsonModule": true,
"isolatedModules": true,
"noEmit": true,
"jsx": "react-jsx",

/* Linting */
"strict": false,
"noUnusedLocals": true,
"noUnusedParameters": true,
"noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
"strictPropertyInitialization": false
},
"include": ["src"],
"references": [{ "path": "./tsconfig.node.json" }]
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Well, I am stupid.

I thought I had already looked at the build command and it was just running vite build. It was not. It was running tsc + vite build. I changed it to just vite build and no more type checking.

Comment: Do you know why the default package.json generated by vite contains tsc as part of the build command? Is there a reason for it?

Comment: @MichaelKruglos See this: https://vitejs.dev/guide/features.html#transpile-only